# Show that $ \frac{{d}}{dx}\sin(x) = \cos(x)$, using summation forms.

Tags: trigonometry, summation

It is well-known that: $ \frac{{d}}{dx}\sin(x) = \cos(x)$. [statement (1)]

Given the definitions:

**$$\sin(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)!} x^{2n-1}$$**

And:

**$$\cos(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n)!} x^{2n}$$**

Can you show that statement (1) is valid?

Comment: The right way to answer this question depends on whether you think it is ok to differentiate infinite sums term by term. In higher math, justification is needed to do that, but in a regular calculus course, you usually just assume that this is ok and keep going. Is this problem for a course?

Comment: @ZachBoyd thanks for the comment. I figured that since Fubini's theorem lets us switch between summation and differential/integral operators when the sum converges on the required domain, we could just move the d/dx operator into sine summation. It does work, of course, but I'm not that well educated in math so I didn't know if this was an appropriate justification for what I did.

No, it's not for a course. I'm just fiddling with math, and being able to manipulate the summation-d/dx order would let me prove a few things for myself. Just interested in math is all. :)

Thanks again.

Comment: Ok cool. It looks like others have discussed the order-changing issue below. I just wanted to make sure you were not looking for a more elementary answer.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

The series formed by differentiating under the summation sign of either the series representation of the sine function or the series representation of the cosine conveges uniformly for all $x$.

Hence, term-by-term differentiation is permissible for all $x$..

Answer (score 0):

Expanding the first one:

$$x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}...$$

Calculate its derivative:

$$1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}...$$

Then calculate the summation form. You're done.

Comment: And how do you justify term-by-term differentiation?

Comment: I like the term-by-term approach, @MCCCS. I'm wondering if you can pull the d/dx operator into the sine summation and prove it 'directly'.

Comment: @Oswald Chisla It's the same thing as the answer. However you can only justify this because the series of functions that you get by differentiating the partial sums converge uniformly. This method will not work in general.

Comment: @oswaldchisala See my posted HINT, which justifies term-by-term differentiation.